# how do I find the max of inputed numbers

Tags: python, max

How do I find the max of inputed numbers? Here's what I have so far. It's giving me an error message: '"int" object is not iterable'

```
def greatest(num):
    for index in range(10):
        num=input('Enter the number of units sold')
    print max(num)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either put them all into a list and then run `max()` on the *list,* or (if you don't need the list for anything else) simply maintain your own maximum with something like:

```
def greatest(num):   # why num here??
    maxnum = -1
    for index in range(10):
        num = input ('Enter the number of units sold')
        if num > maxnum:
            maxnum = num
    print maxnum
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I'm not sure why the num in line 1, im kinda knew to programming. I guess it still works though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accumulate the numbers in a list or some other iterable data structure:

```
def greatest():
    data = [input('Enter the number of units sold') for _ in range(10)]
    print max(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold those numbers that you are getting from the user in a data structure, then find the maximum after you have finished collecting. Right now you are just overriding the value of `num` in each iteration which doesn't help at all since you can't examine the previous input numbers. This is why you are getting an error from `max`, expecting something to iterate over. Going with what you have so far something like this would work,

```
def greatest():
    l = []
    for index in range(10):
        l.append(input('Enter the number of units sold'))
    return max(l)
```

But this would be even better:

```
def greatest():
    return max(input('Enter the number of units sold') for _ in xrange(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because `max`gives you the largest number in a series of numbers, while `input` returns an int.

What you're probably trying to do is this:

```
def greatest(num):
    numbers = []
    for index in range(10):
        numbers.append(input('Enter the number of units sold'))
    print max(numbers)
```